# Navigation Icon causes application to close

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am a newbie to Android Studio but have successfully gone quite far, including a successful login screen. But I am getting stuck at a point.

The navigation icon created using ActionBarDrawerToggle works fine on the homescreen. Then on clicking on any of the options, it successfully loads the fragment. But when I click on the the icon again to go to another fragment, the navigation drawer open but the application closes. The debugger shows no error, it only reports that the onStop and onPause events have been triggered (which are empty since I have no use with them).

I have tried a lot but I am unable to find a solution to this problem.

I even attempted to create a custom view on the ActionBar with a custom ImageButton, and I set a click listener. That worked fine, but I want to use the default method, i.e. ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Open to all suggestions!

My HomeAcivity.java, where I am using the alternate I custom-built.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
    ImageButton drawer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        db.deleteUsers();
        session.setLogin(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }else if(id == android.R.id.home){
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_home_fragment, profileFragment, profileFragment.getTag()).commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.profile_heading);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cmi) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_inspire) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: The logcat should show an error

Comment: You really shouldn't call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` outside of OnCreate

Comment: The logcat shows no error, it shows that the onPause and onStop activity has been triggered. @cricket_007

Comment: I have removed the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` as per what you suggested. @cricket_007

Comment: Like I said, if the app closes, then there is something wrong, and the logcat should show it. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you expect in an answer

Comment: The logcat shows the following:
`I/Activity: [AppLaunch] activity.onPause +`,
`I/Activity: [AppLaunch] activity.onPause -`,
`I/Activity: [AppLaunch] activity.onStop +`,
`I/Activity: [AppLaunch] activity.onStop -`.. @cricket_007

Comment: Where are you logging those? Those aren't errors, though... Can you create a [mcve], please? Start commenting sections of code until something works. Your drawer code in looks okay, but the action bar code in questionable